# usage of "put effort in"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

As per [a post](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/1345795), "put effort in" and "make an effort" pretty much mean the same thing.

However, "put effort in" appear to be not a standard use of "effort", as there is no such an example in [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/effort?q=effort%20)

Could "put effort in" be used in formal settings?

Comment: The linked post does not mention "make an effort" which doesn't mean quite the same thing. It is usually used to stir someone who isn't making any attempt to help. But "put in effort" means more like being involved in a project of some kind, either alone or in a group.

Answer (score 1):

**Make an effort** generally means you give it a try. [To indicate that you put a lot of work into something, see **put effort into** below.]

- "He really made an effort" - He really tried to do it (some task)
- "He really made an effort on the project" - same.

**Make an effort** can also be a sarcastic jab at someone who is not really trying (or not trying enough for your liking):

- "At least make an effort!" is similar to "At least pretend you're trying!"
- "At least HE made an effort!" implies that you did not.

**Put in effort** or **Put effort in** are not really used (in my experience), even though they may be technically correct.

Better to use **put ... effort into** to convey that you worked hard on something (even if the results were not there):

- "He put considerable effort into the task (but he just didn't have the necessary skill)."
- "She put a lot more effort into the group project than the rest of us."